# keep intermediate files defined by wildcards in makefile

Tags: makefile

I've defined a series of data-processing steps with a `Makefile` but find that the files belonging to the intermediate steps are deleted by Make. In the following example, the files `processed_%.txt` are always deleted.

```
#make some simple data
#echo "test data X" > test_x.txt
#echo "test data y" > test_y.txt

x = test_x.txt
y = test_y.txt

#these are deleted
processed_%.txt: ${x} ${y}
        cat $< > $@

#these remain in the directory
processed_again_%.txt: processed_%.txt
        cat $< > $@

all: processed_again_x.txt processed_again_y.txt
```

Can anyone explain what is happening and how to disable/control this behavior?

thanks,
zachcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how [chains of implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) work.

> The second difference is that if make does create b in order to update something else, it deletes b later on after it is no longer needed. Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also does not exist after make. make reports the deletion to you by printing a ‘rm -f’ command showing which file it is deleting.

and you can control this behavior by marking the file as `.SECONDARY`

> You can prevent automatic deletion of an intermediate file by marking it as a secondary file. To do this, list it as a prerequisite of the special target .SECONDARY. When a file is secondary, make will not create the file merely because it does not already exist, but make does not automatically delete the file. Marking a file as secondary also marks it as intermediate.

Comment: Also, just listing the intermediate files as prerequisites of any target will be sufficient to make them "non-intermediate".  You could create a phony target, for example, that just built the "intermediate" files, for debugging maybe, and that would do the trick.